# (Godot) Sprite bounces off Tiles after Walking (Bug?)

Tags: sprite, godot

My Sprite always jumps a little when walking a straight distance. No hitbox is overlapping and I use move and slide with snap

Comment: Can you copy your movement code into the question and add some information about what your character is walking on? Is it one big flat collision shape, or many small blocks?

Comment: It's many small Blocks with a tileMap. The Movement Code is : if Input legit is pressed then : movement.x = -1 * Speed